# Inherit URL path on Google Analytics Experiments

Tags: google-analytics, ab-testing, google-experiments

I want to run an A/B test using Google Analytics Content Experiments to test different pages.

I would like to know if there is a way to define variations inheriting parts of the URL path. I read the documentation but seems that Analytics only inherits [URL dynamic parameters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2664470?hl=en&ref_topic=1745208).

My URLs look like:

```
https://example.com/page1/{USER-DATA-123}
```

where `{USER-DATA-123}` contains some data related to current user and it's different for every visitor.

And I want to create this experiment:

```
Original page: https://example.com/page1/{USER-DATA-123}
Variation page 1: https://example.com/page2/{USER-DATA-123}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was investigaing the same issue, just had to test two desings of this page https://labiteam.com/services/landing-page. There are two variants:

1. Turn your static urls with id sessions into dynamic. According to this manual https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2664470?hl=en it should work
2. You can customize testing script manually, though I doubt it's a practical decision

Upd: Also, one more suggestion. Forget about A/B experiments, just make your URLs appear randomly (coding it manually) and set goals to each url.